# Align elements on center of the navigation bar, except one (or more) elements

Tags: css, r, flexdashboard

I have this [application](https://giovani.shinyapps.io/0_example/), written in `RMarkdown`:

I tried to center the `.navbar` elements, except for an icon on the right. This code works well:

```
.navbar-nav {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translatex(-50%);
}
```

But the icon is in the center:

[image]

I wanted only this icon to be at the "initial position". I tried to force this permanence with this code:

```
.fa-question-circle {
  float: right !important;
}
```

But nothing happened.

**Edit**

When resize screen, the icon `.fa-question-circle` gets out of hamburguer menu when I click on it:

[image]

Hamburger menu code:

```
@media (max-width: 950px) {
  .navbar-header {
    float: none;
  }
  .navbar-left,.navbar-right {
    float: none !important;
  }
  .navbar-toggle {
    display: block;
  }
  .navbar-collapse {
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
  }
  .navbar-fixed-top {
    top: 0;
    border-width: 0 0 1px;
  }
  .navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: none!important;
  }
  .navbar-nav {
    display: block !important;
    float: none!important;
    margin-top: 7.5px;
  }
  .navbar-nav>li {
    float: none;
  }
  .navbar-nav>li>a {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .collapse.in{
    display: block !important;
  }
}
```

I'm almost certain that the adjustment needs to be made here:

```
.navbar-left,.navbar-right {
  float: none !important;
}
```

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
.navbar-left,.navbar-right {
  float: none !important; 
  display: block !important; 
  position: absolute !important;
}
```

**Objective:** The "icon" should be the last option on the hamburger menu. Like this:

[image]

Comment: Post Your markup?

Comment: Add u r html code

Comment: I written in RMarkdown. See my edit. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the link you posted,
you need to add this in your CSS

```
.navbar-right {
    left: auto;
    right: 10px;
    transform: none;
}
```

On your second problem

Add this CSS to your ul

```
ul {
    display: flex;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Glad to help you. Please accept the answer. So that the community gets to know that it is a solved question

Comment: I have a new problem. When I decrease the screen size, the "Contato" element will leak to a navigation bar. How to adjust this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

### Navigation bar with left, right and centre aligned element.

> CSS for nav responsive and style

```
<style>


.topnav {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.topnav-centered a {
  float: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.topnav-right {
  float: right;
}

</style>
```

> HTML code for navigation

```
<div class="topnav">

  <!-- Centered link -->
  <div class="topnav-centered">
    <a href="#center" class="active">Center Nav Element</a>
  </div>

  <!-- Left-aligned links (default) -->
  <a href="#left1">Left 1</a>
  <a href="#left2">Left 2</a>

  <!-- Right-aligned links -->
  <div class="topnav-right">
    <a href="#right1">Right 1</a>
    <a href="#right2">Right 2</a>
  </div>

</div>
```